# django - how to add ForeignKey's ForeignKey (3 level) field to the form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to make an inventory system with 4 models - Category, ProductGroup, Product, Stock - as given below.

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=75,null=False,blank=False, unique=True)
    parent=TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

class ProductGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False, blank=False)
    category=TreeForeignKey('category.Category', null=False,blank=False)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_group=models.ForeignKey('productgroup.ProductGroup', null=False,blank=False)
    manufacturer=models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, null=False,blank=False)
    product_type=models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE,)
    opening_stock=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

TRANSACTION_TYPE=(('I','Stock In'),('O','Stock Out'))
class Stock(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey('product.Product', blank=False,null=False)
    quantity=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    ttype=models.CharField(max_length=1,verbose_name="Transaction type",choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE, blank=False)
```

and I have a model form for recording Stock-In/Out as follows.

```
class StockInOutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock       
        fields=['product','quantity','date']
```

(and two separate views for StockIn and StockOut to set **ttype**)

Since the table products is basically a permutation of ProductGroup,Manufacturer and ProductType it will contain a huge set of records.

I need to add the Cateogry and ProductGroup fields as chained  fields so that the  for Product.name in the form would contain only a filtered set.

Kindly give some insights on how to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Exprator
To get the fields in  the desired order, I've used the following code.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class StockInOutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user','')
        super(StockInOutForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category']=TreeNodeChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
        self.fields['product_group']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ProductGroup.objects.filter(id=0))
        self.fields['product']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ProductGroup.objects.filter(id=0))
        original_fields = self.fields

        new_order = OrderedDict()
        for key in ['category','product_group', 'product','quantity','date']:
            new_order[key] = original_fields[key]
        self.fields = new_order
```